# How to use okHttp library for ver 4.9

Tags: android, request, okhttp

Android-Studio okHttp3

[image]

What's the problem here picture. I have implemented this version of okHttp:

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3")
```

```
error: cannot find symbol
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
        ^
  symbol:   class Request
  location: class MainActivity
```

How do we call the response with okHttp 4.9.0?

Comment: Please check with your imports. Make sure you are using the correct one.

Comment: Import was corect but Response class removed maybe. Deprecated some methods but whichs?